# How to make MATLAB identify dependency when packaging toolbox

Tags: matlab, package, dependencies, toolbox

I have a folder where I have defined some custom scripts. Those scripts make use of functions and classes defined in toolboxes such as the Communications Toolbox and the DSP System Toolbox.

When I try to package the folder into a toolbox, the Dependency Analyzer doesn't identify any of the toolboxes that the scripts rely on. How do I rectify this?

For instance, if I have just the following lines inside a matlab script and in a matlab function file as well, both inside the folder, should MATLAB not identify the Parallel Computing Toolbox as a required add-on when packaging the folder?

```
gcp('nocreate')
delete(gcp('nocreate'));
parpool("local", 1);
```

I tried to see if MATLAB is able to tell the dependencies using the *RequiredFilesAndProducts* on my scripts, but even that failed to list the required toolboxes.

I have also gone through the following MATLAB pages  -

1. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/identify-dependencies.html : The dependency report for the code I included, correctly identifies that the Parallel Computing toolbox is being used.
2. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.codetools.requiredfilesandproducts.html This doesn't list *any* toolboxes as dependencies for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can happen if the code being analysed isn't on MATLAB's path. I put the lines you specified in a script, and when not on the path, `requiredFilesAndProducts` lists only MATLAB; when the script is on the path, I see this:

```
[a,b] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('pkg/usesPctScript.m');
disp(struct2table(b))
                 Name                 Version     ProductNumber    Certain
    ______________________________    ________    _____________    _______

    {'MATLAB'                    }    {'9.12'}           1          true  
    {'Parallel Computing Toolbox'}    {'7.6' }          80          false 
    {'MATLAB Parallel Server'    }    {'7.6' }          94          false 
    {'Polyspace Bug Finder'      }    {'3.6' }         164          false
```

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-and-share-custom-matlab-toolboxes.html), in the "Toolbox Portability" section of the "Package Toolbox" app, it states:

> Products—List of MathWorks® products required by your toolbox. Create
> this list manually.

Comment: It turns out that while the code was indeed on MATLAB's path, I wasn't calling that struct2table function. Calling that gave me the same output as you. So that's one mystery solved, thanks!

Comment: However, when I package the folder as a toolbox, I still don't see those toolboxes identified as dependencies---- which is really the crux of the problem I'm trying to solve

Comment: I'm guessing that 'certain' field being false for all the other toolboxes, has something to do with it?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but reading the doc, I think unfortunately you need to populate the "Products" portion of "Toolbox Portability" manually. I _think_ the "Requirements" piece is about stuff other than MathWorks products.

Comment: I see. Would be really helpful if you could also link the doc you referred to. My google-fu didn't turn up anything useful .

If you could suggest a way to specify the dependent toolboxes in the .prj file - so that they get automatically installed - that would be great!

Comment: This page https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-and-share-custom-matlab-toolboxes.html . (I've never used that functionality before, so I had to look up the doc to even know where to begin!). One has to read quite carefully the description of the "Requirements" and compare with "Toolbox Portability" - which states "Products—List of MathWorks® products required by your toolbox. Create this list manually."

Comment: Okay, I feel really dumb now. I must have stared at that page a hundred times now. Never noticed the Toolbox Portability section, or the fact that the MATLAB products list needed to populated manually. It's a lifesaver - thanks a ton!